# JavaScript - dropdown validation selection

Tags: javascript, validation

I have 3 `dropdowns`, I would like to check in JavaScript that at least one selection has been made, if not display a message. What would be the simplest way to do it in JavaScript?

id: dropdown1
id: dropdown2
id: dropdown3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// need to make sure the first dropdown option is blank, then...

var dd1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
var dd2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
var dd3 = document.getElementById('dropdown3');

```
if (
  (dd1.selectedIndex == 0) && 
  (dd2.selectedIndex == 0) && 
  (dd3.selectedIndex == 0)
) {  
  alert('need to select at least one')
}
```

Comment: or if(!dd1.selectedIndex || !dd2.selectedIndex || !dd3.selectedIndex)

Comment: @mkoryak: Need to use '&&' between the conditions, or remove the extra '!' before the dd2 & dd3.  ...but you got me thinking that the test for null doesn't work anyway - need to do something like make the first option a blank, and test to see if the index >0.  I'm revising my answer